# typescript enum from array

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

Currently, I am getting an array of UserRole objects from the back-end. Each UserRole has an Id (int) and a Role (string).

UserRoles[ ] looks like...

```
[
   //{id, role}
     {1, Viewer},
     {2, Owner},
     {3, Admin}
]
```

_models\userRole.ts

```
export interface UserRole {
    id: number,
    role: string
}
```

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    userRoles: UserRole[]

    constructor(...) {
        http.get<UserRole[]>(baseurl + "api/UserRoles/GetUserRoles").subscribe(result => { 
            this.userRoles = result; 
            }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    ...
}
```

#### The issue:

I'd like to turn it into an enum for use in limiting what is presented to the user. For example,

```
<div *ngIf="user.userRoleId >= userRoles.Owner ">
```

Should I be sending something other than an array of objects up from the backend (which is an ASP.NET Core controller)?

Is there a way to generate the enum immediately from the api call?

Or is there a way to convert the array of objects to an enum?

Comment: You can use the response to create an object, declare userRoles:any={}; and in the subscribe: result=>{result.forEach(p=>this.userRoles[result.role]=result.id)}. It's not an enum -you has no help when you write your code-, but you can use this.userRoles.Owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by Eliseo, here's what I ended up doing:

I retrieved the UserRoles as an array, then did a foreach loop on that array, and added the roles and id to an object.

**home.component.ts**

```
//imports

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    user: User;
    userRoles: any = {};

    constructor(private userRoleService: UserRoleService, private alertify: AlertifyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadUserRoles();
    }

    loadUserRoles() {
        this.userRoleService.getUserRoles().subscribe((res: UserRole[]) => {
            res.forEach(p => this.userRoles[p.role] = p.id);
        });
    }
```

**userRole.service.ts**

```
//imports

@Injectable()
export class UserRoleService {
    baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private authHttp: HttpClient) {}

    getUserRoles(): Observable<UserRole[]> {
        return this.authHttp
            .get<UserRole[]>(this.baseUrl + "UserRoles");
    }
}
```

**home.component.html** implementation

```
<div *ngIf="user.userRoleId >= userRoles.Owner ">
    ...
</div>
```